# Someone can provide some code example for Raphael JS events?

Tags: javascript, events, raphael

I don't know how to use Raphael JS events.

I need some example. I see the documentation and a function must be passed, but is not working.

Someone can provide some example of how to get the mouse position of a click in the canvas?

**EDIT**: I see in documentation events for `Element`. This will work for `Paper`? How I create a `mousedown()` event for `Paper`?

Comment: Are you using Raphael 2?

Comment: @Radagaisus Raphael JS, a javascript library for drawnig, graphics, etc.

Comment: I know :) a few days ago version 2 of the library was published. Thus my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
clickEvent = function(){
    alert("Hello World!");
}

paper = Raphael(...);
paper.raphael.click(clickEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p.mouseover(function () {
   p.stop().animate({transform: "s1.1 1.1 " + cx + " " + cy}, ms, "elastic");
   txt.stop().animate({opacity: 1}, ms, "elastic");
}).mouseout(function () {
   p.stop().animate({transform: ""}, ms, "elastic");
   txt.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, ms);
});
```

check out the source code in the [Raphael examples](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html).

Here's another example with a click event:

```
movers[2].click(function () {
  this.cx = this.cx || 300;
  this.animate({cx: this.cx, "stroke-width": this.cx / 100, fill: this.cx - 100 ? "hsb(.2, .75, .75)" : "#000", "fill-opacity": +!!(this.cx - 100)}, 1000, "<");
  this.cx = this.cx == 300 ? 100 : 300;
});
```

which is taken from the [easing example](http://raphaeljs.com/easing.html).

I don't know if the code will work on version 2, though